# Leibniz's rule in $W^{1,\,p}(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Is it true?

If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and $u,v\in W^{1,\,p}(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$, then $uv\in W^{1,\,p}(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ and
$$\nabla(uv)=u\nabla v+v\nabla u.$$

I proved for $2\leq p$.

Comment: You may want to show your prove. Maybe it extends also to $p < 2$?

Answer (score 1):

This is true for $p\geqslant 1$. The case $p=1$, being a limiting one, 
requires more efforts. It will be sufficient to establish  the rule
$$
\partial_j(uv)=u\partial_j v+v\partial_j u,\quad j=,\dots,n,\tag{1}
$$
for the weak derivatives $\partial_j$ just in case $p=1$, with the equality
$(1)$ understood in a weak sense, *i.e.*, as an integral identity
$$
\int\limits_{\Omega}uv\partial_j\varphi\,dx=
-\int\limits_{\Omega}(u\partial_j v+v\partial_j u)\varphi\,dx\quad \forall\,
\varphi\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)\tag{2}
$$
where $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ denotes the space of infinitely differentiable 
functions compactly supported in the domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, 
$n\geqslant 2$. The basic idea underlying the proof is to approximate 
$u,v$ by smooth functions. While smooth functions are dense in the Sobolev 
space $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ *w.r.t.* its norm, it is not the case with the Lebesgue
space $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. However, essentially bounded functions can be
approximated in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ by smooth functions in the weak$^\ast$-
topology which is enough to establish the identity $(2)$.

Denote by $\omega_{\varepsilon}$ a mollifier, *i.e.*,
let $\omega_{\varepsilon}=\varepsilon^{-n}\omega(x/\varepsilon)$, $\varepsilon>0$, 
with some $\omega\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ such that
$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\omega(x)\,dx=1,\quad
{\rm supp\,}\omega\subset B_1=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon\,|x|<1\}.
$$
 Take and fix an arbitrary test function $\varphi\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$
 to be substituted into identity $(2)$, and notice there is some 
 $\delta\overset{\rm def}{=}{\rm dist}({\rm supp\,}\varphi,\partial\Omega)>0$.
 Denote $\Omega_{\delta}=\{x\in\Omega\,\colon\,{\rm dist}(x,\partial\Omega)>\delta\}$
 and notice that ${\rm supp\,}\varphi\subset\overline{\Omega}_{\delta}$.
Extensions of $u,v$ by zero outside $\Omega$ denote by $\tilde{u},\tilde{v}$, 
and let $u_{\varepsilon}=\omega_{\varepsilon}\ast\tilde{u},\;
v_{\varepsilon}=\omega_{\varepsilon}\ast\tilde{v}$. It is clear that
$u_{\varepsilon}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ while
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\|u-u_{\varepsilon}\|_{W^{1,1}
(\Omega_{\delta})}=0.\tag{3}
$$
Convergence of $u_{\varepsilon}$ in the norm of $L^{\infty}(\Omega_{\delta})$ 
requires $u\in C(\Omega)$ which may not be the case, but it is clear that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int\limits_{\Omega_{\delta}}u_{\varepsilon}\psi\,dx=
\int\limits_{\Omega_{\delta}}u\,\psi\,dx\quad \forall\, 
\psi\in L^1(\Omega_{\delta}),\tag{4}
$$
*i.e.*, smooth functions $u_{\varepsilon}$ converge to $u$ in the weak$^\ast$-
topology on $L^{\infty}(\Omega_{\delta})$ being dual to $L^1(\Omega_{\delta})$.

The fact that $u_{\varepsilon},v_{\varepsilon}\in C^{\infty}(\Omega_{\delta})$ implies
$$
\int\limits_{\Omega_{\delta}}u_{\varepsilon}v_{\varepsilon}\partial_j\varphi\,dx=
-\int\limits_{\Omega_{\delta}}(u_{\varepsilon}\partial_j v_{\varepsilon}+
v_{\varepsilon}\partial_j u_{\varepsilon})\varphi\,dx, 
$$
whence by $(3),(4)$ follows $(2)$.